# Can't upgrade in Xubuntu 12.10

Tags: 12.10, upgrade, xubuntu

I can't upgrade anything at all. I can't even open the software updater or the software center. And if I try to upgrade through the terminal I only get messages about error and failing.

I want to upgrade to a newer version of xubuntu and I am at a loss, what to do?

Answer (score 0):

How I do a main Xubuntu update:

- Download the (latest) version of Xubuntu that you want.
- Copy it on a removable storage device.
- Boot your device with Xubuntu in it.
- Click on Install Ubuntu.
- Update your system via the "Update Ubuntu" option in the installer.